# Android ListView Fast Scroll - onItemLongClick event is triggered when using slider

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onlongclicklistener, fastscroll

I have encountered a really weird behavior of Fast Scroll function of ListView component (`listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);`
) on **Android 4.4, 5.0, 5.1** (4.2.2 and older versions work ok).

If the `OnItemLongClickListener` is set on ListView the behavior is following:

1) Click on "Fast Scroll Slider" trigger  onItemLongClick event on one of the items in the ListView (not necessarily on the item right under the slider).

2) The same thing happens when the slider is used for slow scrolling (slow movement of finger).

3) When the slider is used for fast scrolling, the "LongClick event animation" is triggered and the following graphical artifact is present after the action:

[image]

Tested many times with many ListView configurations.

Sample Test App source code is here: 
http://ge.tt/517ZIFC2/v/0

It is making the fast scroll function useless. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I am using the setFastScrollEnabled but I don't see any problems. I think the issue is likely to be in getView() since it is the method to update the row items in ListView.  Another, it seems you have several problems with your events, this is related to code or the layouts.

Comment: For debugging, disable/remove the Fast Scroll and see if all is fine. I find the Fast scroll is not so useful. It does show the position in the listview well however :-)